# Change header color multistore prestashop

Tags: colors, prestashop-1.6, multistore

I use prestashop 1.6.1.2 with multistore option.

I would like to change the header color for each shop.

I am using the same theme because the duplication doesn't work with the current theme.

In the header.tpl I added :

```
if {$shop_name=="myshop"} {literal}<style> .header-top { background-color: #d6644a; }</style>{/literal}{/if}
```

and I test with `if {$id-shop=="3"}`

but nothing changed in the header

Answer (score 0):

In your header.tpl change this part

```
<body{if isset($page_name)} id="{$page_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"{/if} class="{if isset($page_name)}{$page_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}{if isset($body_classes) && $body_classes|@count} {implode value=$body_classes separator=' '}{/if}{if $hide_left_column} hide-left-column{else} show-left-column{/if}{if $hide_right_column} hide-right-column{else} show-right-column{/if}{if isset($content_only) && $content_only} content_only{/if} lang_{$lang_iso}">
```

with this to include the shop´s name in the body class

```
<body{if isset($page_name)} id="{$page_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"{/if} class="{if isset($page_name)}{$page_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}{if isset($shop_name) && Configuration::get('PS_MULTISHOP_FEATURE_ACTIVE')} {$shop_name|lower|replace:' ':'_'}{/if}{if isset($body_classes) && $body_classes|@count} {implode value=$body_classes separator=' '}{/if}{if $hide_left_column} hide-left-column{else} show-left-column{/if}{if $hide_right_column} hide-right-column{else} show-right-column{/if}{if isset($content_only) && $content_only} content_only{/if} lang_{$lang_iso}">
```

Then in your css you can use

```
.my_store .header {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: I have make all  the changes and I added css in the globla css:
.shop_pro.header-top {
    background-color: red!important;}
But nothing change

Comment: I have the same problem, I clear all caches(prestashop and browser)

Answer (score 0):

better that way with space between

```
.shop_pro .header-top {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: yes I have this
<!--[if IE 8]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->

Answer (score 0):

better this way, with  space between

```
.my_store .header {
    background: red;
}
```

Check you page source code. Should be something like that with the shop name

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body id="index" class="index my_store hide-left-column hide-right-column lang_en">
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like that with the shop name

```
<body id="index" class="index my_store hide-left-column hide-right-column lang_en">
```